# CSS styling of definition lists

Tags: html, css

I have a list of title/values.  I am thinking a definition list is the way to go.  I want the title and definition to be on the same line, and I do not want the titles to have the same width of each other, but for each to have it's width based on the amount of text in the title.  I also want the definitions to stay within their blocks, and not to bleed under the title.  Lastly, I want it to work with IE7 and greater.

Okay, I come up with the following HTML/CSS, and it almost works.  I have a live example at http://jsfiddle.net/s45Kd/ since I couldn't figure out how to add CSS with the stackoverflow window (is it possible?).  Two problems.

First, how do I force definitions to break even if they do not have any white-space in them (i.e. "email")?

Second, why do long definitions eventually bleed under the title (i.e. "some text")?

While I would appreciate a "just do this", I am more looking for why this happens so I better understand.

Thank you

```
<style type="text/css">
    dl,dt,dd {padding:0;margin:0;}
    dl {width:200px;border:1px dashed black;}
    dt {float:left;font-weight:bolder; padding-right:5px; border:1px dashed red;}
    dd {border:1px dashed blue;}
</style> 
<dl>
    <dt>First Name:</dt><dd>Bob</dd>
    <dt>Last Name:</dt><dd>Johnson</dd>
    <dt>Email:</dt><dd>bob.johnson@stackoverflow.com</dd>
    <dt>Phone Number:</dt><dd>(555) 555-1212</dd>
    <dt>Some Text:</dt><dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</dd>
    <dt>Birthday</dt><dd>January 1st</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If you want the title and the label to appear on the same line, why would you use `dl` markup, which by default puts them on separate lines? Using `table` markup would give you better default rendering and better possibilities for styling. And `dl` is no more “semantic” than `table` (actually, less).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela.  Maybe, but don't want a single width column for the first column.  Maybe label tags?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela.  Also, should whether default behavior on one or two lines influence my use of one tag over another?

Comment: It’s not clear at all what you want. Varying width for the titles makes the rendering messy. But if you really want that, you can use just `<div><b>title</b><span>value</span></div>` and then style the `span` as an inline block. Regarding e-mail addresses, they simply should not be broken across lines, but you can throw in e.g. `<wbr>` tags to indicate allowed line breaks if you really must.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela.  The artist designer came up with the varying widths.  Sounds like your recommendation is not even to use definition lists for this application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first, the word wrap can be solved by setting:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

For the second, the key is to set `overflow: hidden;` on both the `dt` and `dd` elements, while still floating only the `dt`.

Demo in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLPej/108/

Comment: Thanks Metadept.  Almost!  I would like the value/definition or what ever you want to call it to stay on the right hand column, and not position itself under the title.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, so it's strictly two columns? You may want to wrap the `dt` and `dd` in divs to accomplish that, but let me play around and see what I can do.

Comment: Yes, I can create the visual aspects using other tags, but got to believe a good semantic approach is possible.  I've been struggling for days and are about to give up.  Note that I don't the first "title" column to have the same width for each row.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1032531 Ok, think I managed to get it working as desired, with some help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653246/definition-list-side-by-side-without-wrapping-too-long-lines